# How the mask can be used in aggregate memory in chisel?

Tags: chisel

I'm tring to use aggregate memory in chisel.

As recommended in github, https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3-wiki/blob/master/Chisel-Memories.md

My code looks like follows:

```
class Interface(val w:Int) extends Bundle{
  val a: UInt = UInt(w.W)
  val b: UInt = UInt(w.W)
  val c: UInt = UInt(w.W)
}

val mem = Mem(16,new Interface(4))
```

Then I use mask as below:

```
mem.write(io.addr, inter, mask)
```

where the type of 'inter' is Interface, the type of 'mask' is Vec[Bool]

The following error is given:

```
Cannot prove that mytest.Interface <:< chisel3.Vec[_].
```

I have done some searching, found that mask can only be used when the memory is defined by Vec.

There is any solution to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, `mask` can only be used when the data type of the memory is a `Vec`.

You didn't describe how exactly you'd like the `mask` to correspond to the interface, but I'm assuming you would have a `Vec` of size 3, one bit for each `a`, `b`, and `c`.

The simplest solution is to just use `Vec(3, UInt(4.W))`:

```scala
val mem = Mem(16, Vec(3, UInt(4.W)))
```

If you then want to read and write as if it were actually made of `Interface`, you can cast:

```scala
mem.write(io.addr, inter.asTypeOf(Vec(3, UInt(4.W)), mask)
```

These casts are a little verbose, you can create type aliases to make the code more concise and maintainable:

```
val w = 4
val memType = Vec(3, UInt(w.W))
val intfType = new Interface(w)

val mem = Mem(16, memType)
mem.write(io.addr, inter.asTypeOf(memType), mask)

val read: Interface = mem.read(io.addr).asTypeOf(intfType)
```